# Laravel Homestead - I can ping homestead.app but I can't access in homestead.app in browser

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

Well:

I can access the files in the virtul server through vagrant SSH.

I can ping homestead.app through CMD.

I can ping the IP 192.160.10.10 through CMD.

But i can't access it through the browser.

if i enter 127.0.0.1:2222 in browser i get this:

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6
Protocol mismatch.
```

this is my Homestead.yaml file:

```
    ---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:\projects\PHP
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/smr/public
      hhvm: true

databases:
    - laraveldb

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

and this is the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 activate.adobe.com
192.168.10.10 homestead.app
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see a Typo:

```
sites:
    - map: homsetead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/smr/public
      hhvm: true
```

Change the map to `homestead.app` and tell us

Comment: @Kirk Beard Sorry for that it's only because i changed the real alias. Corrected.

Comment: No problem, what error you get on the browser, 404?

Comment: i get a HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Check the nginx logs, I think homestead worked with Nginx, and if you don't find any logs matching the same time you accesed your site, check the PHP logs

Comment: Since you changed your configuration, you probably have to re-provision Homestead. Run `vagrant provision` and then access the domain again. You can see what sites are available by SSHing into Homestead, and running `ls -al /etc/nginx/sites-available`.

Comment: I understand that he did not change the configuration, but he obfuscated the real domain name in this question and mistyped himself here on SO